# Telerik WIdgets - How do I create identical controls where one is slightly different?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, widget

```
<telerik:RadContextMenu runat="server" ID="radMenu" EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadow="true" OnClientItemClicked="MenuItemClick"> 
</telerik:RadContextMenu>
```

I am working on creating 6 dynamic Telerik Widgets, which have Edit,Collapse,Expand menu at top of each widget.

How to disable the "Edit" menu only for 1 widget and enable for other 5 widgets on the same page?

Comment: Try to do that conditionally for this very widget, by incorporating logic which hides the edit option dynamically when an instance of this widget is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the clicked widget in the `OnClientItemClicked` event and check if it's the first widget then disable the context menu via the client-side [disable() function](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/menu-radmenuitem-client-side.html) shown here.